# Lightning component for search with popup

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

Are there any built-in `lightning` or `ui` components that represent a search bar with popup that contain the search results and pops up every time user types something in the search bar?

**UPD:** if you go to Calender -> Create New Event there is a search component that is exactly what I need but I'm not sure whether it is something from the standard package and can be reused in my code
[image]

Comment: for reference purposes, what do you mean with "popup" ? could you include a screenshot for clarification purposes (it would seem that you are refering to a dropdown list with recommended results or something similar)?

Comment: I dont think so they have but you can try the custom one... 
[Custom Lookup in Lightning](http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/17/re-usable-custom-lookup/) this is not the exactly what you want but quite similar i Guess... you can take reference from it

Comment: @glls please see update to the post

Comment: @SagarHinsu, thanks, I'll refer to this if I don't find a standard one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the [lightning:combobox](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_combobox.htm) was supposed to be, but they kind of forgot to make it work this way; it actually behaves just like a `lightning:select` instead. You might want to consider just implementing one yourself rather than wait until it becomes available.